# PowerShell. While statement continues executing command after condition has been changed to false

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that waits for a Service to start:

```
$ServiceName = 'asComSvc'
$Service = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
While ( $Service.status -ne 'Running' ) {
     Get-Date -Format hh:mm.ss
     Write-Host -Object "Waiting for the service to start..."
     Start-Sleep -s 5
}
Get-Date -Format hh:mm.ss
Write-Host Service started succesfully
```

Yet when the condition changes from true to false in `-ne 'Running'` the script is still being executed.
If the Service is already running (timestamp 10:47.59-10:48.01 on the screenshot), then the script behaves as expected:
[image]
What causes such behavior?

Comment: There are probably multiple `asComSrv` services of which at least one `-ne 'Running'`, see [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators):   ***When the input of an operator is a scalar value, the operator returns a Boolean value. When the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression. If there are no matches in the collection, comparison operators return an empty array.***

Comment: In other words, you probably want to do this: `While ( -not ($Service.status -eq 'Running'))`, meaning: "while there aren't *any* `asComSrv` services running"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your while loop you are not checking the current status of the service, you are checking the status of the service when you first loaded the variable `$Service` which won't change until you clear it and completely re load it. Try changing your while loop to look like this.

```
While ( (Get-Service -Name $ServiceName).Status -ne 'Running' ) {
     Get-Date -Format hh:mm.ss
     Write-Host -Object "Waiting for the service to start..."
     Start-Sleep -s 5
}
```

This will re run the check each time the while loop is triggered which is every 5 seconds

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to keep using the variable after, after the `Start-Sleep` command, add in another check of the service: `$Service = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName`